# Using a single dim array to assign values to a two dim array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have the following code

```
double[,] var = new double[5,10];
double[] var2 = new double[10];

int a;

for (a=0;a<10;a++)
    var[0,a] = var2[a];
```

Is there a way in C# to just assign the entire row without for loops?
the following syntax is incorrect, but curious if there exists a way to do it.

```
var[0] = var2;
```

Comment: no, you should assign all the items separately.

Comment: You may want to look at `jagged arrays`

Answer (score 0):

There is not for 2D arrays but for jagged arrays

```
double[][] var = new double[5][];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    var[i] = new double[10];

double[] var2 = new double[10];

var[0] = var2;
```

Note that after these statements `var[0]` references `var2`. If you want a copy, you would have to create an empty array of the right size and copy the contents of the other array into it:

```
var[0] = new double[10];
var2.CopyTo(var[0], 0);
```